# Trouble Accessing Azure WCF relay Getting "The endpoint was not found. Endpoint does not exist." Error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-relay

I have been trying to use Azure WCF relay with two ASP applications as Given in the link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/service-bus-dotnet-hybrid-app-using-service-bus-relay

the example explains to create a console server and MVC Client application to connect using azure service bus relay.

I created RootManageSharedAccessKey as mentioned and Given primary key to both of the applications.

However after implementation of the same, I have been getting this issue.

```
Endpoint= http://mynewns01.servicebus.windows.net/products
SharedAccessKey  
O+rmo4DGKpPmg23XPj5HmYmsMChwzLumPKgxxxxxxxxxxx=
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80131501
  Message=The endpoint was not found. Endpoint does not exist. TrackingId:91e084d8-d143-4c7f-a2f6-7ca4cb372xx7_G4, SystemTracker:mynewns01.servicebus.windows.net:products, Timestamp:2019-10-08T13:51:46. Please ensure that you can connect to the internet using HTTP port 80 and TCP port 9350.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at ProductsServer.IProducts.GetProducts()
   at ProductsWeb.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in D:\ProductsPortal\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 32
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase con
```

Can anyone suggest me what did went wrong with the example I followed?

Comment: Is it http or https?

Comment: @AzharKhorasany It's http

Answer (score 0):

@Azhar As per the link it is TCP.